# Why does document.getElementsByClassName return an array here?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for a stupid question, but maybe someone can explain it to me.  On w3school web-site you can find a modal example. And in order to close the modal they use the following line of code:

HTML:

```
<span class="close">&times;</span>
```

Script:

```
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

Why to use array here? I tried this code without this array and it doesn’t work. I tried to use different indexes in this array and it also doesn’t work.

Why do we use [0] here and how does it exactly work?

Comment: because its getElement**s**  ? so potentially more than one ... ??

Comment: But why does not simple getElement without an array work here?

Comment: @VladNorton, I don't think you get it. Did you see the bold letter in Wilom's comment?

Comment: Yes I see, I tried to use getElement. without S. And it simply doesn't work this way. Modal can't be closed

Comment: Why did you think that method exists without `s`? Could you reference the documentation for it?

Comment: 1. It's not exactly an array, just an array-like type of data called DOM node collection.

 2. It will always be a collection because that is what you'd expect from a method like `document.getElementsByClassName` - notice the element**s** in its name. There can be more than one element being retrieved by `document.getElementsByClassName`.

As a developer, you want an API to be sure to **always return the same type of data**, so it wouldn't make sense to return a DOM node (instead of a collection containing one node item) in case only one element matches.

Comment: An element such as class and tag can be used more then once on document. 

if you know id of an element can be use document.getElementById  it's return elements directly

Comment: Thank you guys! Now I see it clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can assign a `class` to more than one element in your HTML document. `getElementsByClassName` does exactly that: An array of all HTML elements which got the given class assigned to them. The `[0]` picks the first (and in your case only) element from that array.

If you want to give an unique identifier to a HTML element, assign an `id` to it and use `getElementById`.

```
<span id="close">&times;</span>

var span = document.getElementById("close");
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), it returns an array of child elements.

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

In your case, you have only one DOM element having class 'close'. That's why it returns an array of one element.